# limit file size `node --prof` file size

Tags: node.js, profiling

I want to do profiling in order to check what cause slowness in production environment.

In order to do that I want to use build in profiling tool of node.js which goes with flag `node --prof index.js`.

I'm afraid that the file size might be huge so I want to limit the file size.

Is there any way to do that?

I already looked into the documentation but couldn't find any reference.

- https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/
- https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/V8-Profiler
- https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_prof_process